# Can I use password_hash() to validate the sender?

Tags: php

I need check on my server if I received a trusty message from sender. Basically I have a private key that only the **Sender** (client) and the **Receiver** (server) knows what is. The Sender generate a *public key* (based on private key) and send it to Receiver, with the action to execute. The Receiver check if this public key is valid. If it is, execute what Sender wants.

My doubt here is how I need hash the public key. If I need use a simple hash algo (like `hash(sha256)`) or if I can use the `password_hash()` to it.

**More about the process** (optional reading):

Sender and Receiver knows the private key. Sender generate a public key based on private key, current time and optional additional data. So it send to server with the action, so I send something like that:

```
command:key = 12345678901234567890123456789012
command:timestamp = 1234567890
action:name = truncate:users
```

Receiver will check if `command:key` is valid, regenerating the public key on server side, repeating the same process done by sender, with the same private key. If it pass, it'll check too if this key was used before, and if timestamp is closest to current time (to avoid use older valid keys). If all is valid, so the `action:name` is executed by server and a response is returned to sender.

**Example**:

> **Bob** (client) wants execute on **Alpha** (server) the `truncate-users` function.
>   Bob knows the server private key. So he create a public key (token) to validate your command on server.
>
> Server will receive Bob command and check if your public key is valid, based on server private key. How it is, so server will execute Bob command and return a success value.

The idea is not encrypt Bob message to server, but only tells to server that he is a trusty guy.

Comment: you should never hash a public key. on second reading im not sure if your trying to invent your own version of [Public-key cryptograph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) or not. if you are you sure look at the exiting well established and working version

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to allow my server identify if the received message is trusty. So I have a private key (that only client and server knows) and so client and server can check a public key generated. I think that this wiki is basically what I'm trying to do, really. -- Maybe, except that I don't want decrypt it, but only check if is trusty.

Comment: this is noting new, your much better looking at the implementations of public-private key than building your own

Comment: Check my example. I not wants to reimplements a secure protocol, like HTTPS, but auth the user, for instance. Basically, the public key is the "password" of client to execute a command on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're really asking for is how to compute a *digital signature* for the request. Signatures are used to verify that the request came from the right sender, and that the message has not been tampered with.

It looks like PHP supports signatures through openSSL

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-sign.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-verify.php

I'd suggest that you read up on how to implement a signature system correctly. It's easy to get things wrong - even experts get it wrong fairly frequently - so take the time to understand what you're building and the security risks.

Comment: Make sure you include a timestamp in the request to prevent replay attacks. Signatures only solve part of the can-I-trust-this-request problem. You still need to validate the data, and assume that an attacker can read and replay what goes down the wire.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you are doing correctly, then yes, you can use `password_hash`.  Something like this:

Sender:

```
$key = "super secret";
$timestamp = time();
$action = "truncate:users";
$signature = password_hash($key . $timestamp . $action, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$message = array(
  'command:key' => $signature,
  'command:timestamp' => $timestamp,
  'action:name' => $action
);
send($message);
```

Receiver:

```
$message = receive();
$key = "super secret";
$valid = password_verify($key . $message['command:timestamp'] . $message['action:name'], $message['command:key']);
if ($valid) {
  //message is OK
} else {
  //something is wrong; maybe an attacker?
}
```

Really, this isn't public key cryptography, this is message signing, which  is a pretty standard thing to do.  You could also look into the `hash_hmac` function for this, or use OpenSSL.  Generally, those are better ideas, since it's much easier to mess things up if you try to do it yourself.